# Select from JSONB field with WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Just installed 9.4 and trying to use JSONB field type.

I've made a table with jsonb field and able to select from it:

```
select statistics->'statistics'->'all_trades'->'all'->'all_trades_perc_profit' as profitable_perc FROM  trade_statistics
```

Works fine.

Now I want to filter results based on field value:

```
select statistics->'statistics'->'all_trades'->'all'->'all_trades_perc_profit' as profitable_perc FROM  trade_statistics WHERE profitable_perc > 1

//There is no "profitable_perc" column
```

Does not work.

If I try to convert result to double, does not work either.

```
select cast(statistics->'statistics'->'all_trades'->'all'->'all_trades_perc_profit' as double precision) as profitable_perc FROM  trade_statistics

//cant convert jsonb into double precision
```

**How should I use select results in WHERE clause in case of jsonb?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three corrections have to be made:

- Wrap the the query in a subquery - you cannot reference the `SELECT` list aliases in `WHERE` clause
- Use the `->>` operator to get the value as text
- Cast the text value as integer so you can make the comparison

  ```
  SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT (statistics->'statistics'->'all_trades'->'all'->>'all_trades_perc_profit')::integer as profitable_perc
          FROM  trade_statistics
    ) sq1
    WHERE profitable_perc > 1
  ```